# Symfony2 FOSOAuthServerBundle OAuth authentication without login form

Tags: api, rest, symfony, oauth-2.0, fosoauthserverbundle

I am using the FOSOAuthServerBundle for my API. Since my API is called by a mobile application I do not want to use a login form for the authentication. Unfortunately the documentation says to configure the authentication like this

```
        oauth_authorize:
        pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/auth
        form_login:
            provider: user_provider
            check_path: /oauth/v2/auth_login_check
            login_path: /oauth/v2/auth_login
```

Is there any possibility to get around this `/oauth/v2/auth_login` URL?

I want to get the authentication by something like this:

`www.website.com/oauth/v2/auth?client_id=CLIENT_ID?SomeOtherNecessaryStuff`

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this tutorial could be interesting for you: [How to Authenticate Users with API Keys](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html)

Comment: Yeah but this has nothing to do with OAuth Authentification. The FOSOAuthServerBundle has got already something similar. I want to do my authentication via "OAuth".